# Routing conceptual understanding

Tags: node.js, routes, middleware

I'm creating a Node.js api, and I'm having some difficulty understanding the router middleware.
This is my middleware that runs when you hit the api.

```
app.use("/", index);
app.use("/menu", menu);
```

index-->index.js;
menu-->menu.js 
Now, index.js has a signup and signin router, both using POST. **This is absent in menu.js**
**index.js**

```
router.post("/signup", function(req,res){
router.post("/signin", function(req,res){
```

The problem is as follows:

When my URI is at /menu, the correct page is rendered after invoking middleware #2

When I hit the signup/signin button, it sends an AJAX post request at */signin* or at */signup*, whatever the case might be.

In my understanding,  point #2 should NOT work, since the ajax post request will go to */menu/signup*, for which there is **NO** handler.
Yet, the handler specified for the POST request in **index.js** executes, and the user is able to sign in/up even when on the menu page (URL: /menu) after invoking the /menu middleware
I'm having difficulty understanding WHY this is happening.
Any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: What does this mean: "Yet, the handler specified for the POST request in index.js executes".  Also, can you show how your router is hooked up?

Comment: Once a router is hooked up in Express, it is active for ALL requests from all pages.  You seem to be thinking that when a user is on the `/` page, that somehow only certain routes are active.  That is not how Express works.  Routes are installed when your server starts and are active all the time, for all requests.  You would typically use different URLs from different pages in order to control which route executes.  You can't use request /xxx from /page1 and request /xxx from /page2 and expect them to hit different route handlers.

Comment: @jfriend00 okay...so all the defined routes remain active. But if I've defined to my API to execute menu.js for all  /menu GET requests, I assume that till /menu is active on the URL, it should execute only menu.js

Comment: @jfriend00  a conceptual aside: so if from localhost:port/menu, i make an AJAX request to /signin, does it make the request to localhost/signin, or localhost/menu/signin ?

Comment: If the leading `/` is on the request, then it is domain-relative, not page-relative so an Ajax request to `/signin` would go to `http://localhost/signin`.  If the Ajax request was just to `signin`, then it is page relative so if the page was `http://locahost/menu`, then the Ajax request would go to `http://localhost/menu/signin`.  This is all determined by the browser before the ajax request is made.  You pretty much always want to use leading `/` on your requests so they are always domain-relative.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah, checked out the headers myself on chrome. Didn't know about the leading / rule for AJAX. Thanks a ton! Solved a major doubt for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll post this as an answer since I think it solved your problem.

If you make an Ajax call from a web page without a leading `/` on it such as just `signup`, then the browser interprets that as page relative which means if the page URL is `http://localhost/menu` and you request an ajax call for `signup`, then the browser will request a url for `http://localhost/menu/signup`.

But, if you prefix your ajax request with `/` and request `/signup`, then this is domain-relative so the browser will add the domain and request `http://locahost/signup`.  The path of the current page will not be used.  You nearly always want to use the leading `/` because this gives you a consistent URL request no matter what page you are on.